# jsp/servlet: update on the fly

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Is there any way to change the source code of servlets/JSPs directly on the server, like in php?

Or do I have to compile and upload the full WAR-archive each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deploying as a war, then you need to upload the entire war; that's kind of the point of them.

If you're deploying a pre-exploded war, you can hot-deploy JSP files since they're compiled when they've changed, but servlet/etc. class files will generally require a restart, although that can depend.

Comment: What does it depend on? Also why would class files require a restart, when war-deployment doesn't require one?

Comment: @Dexter A war file deployment re-starts the app, no? I don't know what all it depends on, TC version certainly, what the class contents are (did it change a class already "live" in the system, etc), etc.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought by restart you meant the server

Comment: @Dexter NP. Yeah, in general, shouldn't need to restart the server.